# Does Erlang Mnesia select on an ordered_set give a list in Erlang Term order?

Tags: select, erlang, mnesia, ordered-set

In the documentation it isn't clear to me whether I need to iterate through in order with either next or perhaps foldl (it is mentioned that foldr goes in the opposite order to ordered_set so presuambly foldl goes in the same order) or if I can use select and rely upon it being ordered (assuming ordered_set table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use `select` and rely upon it being ordered (assuming ordered_set table)

[ets:select/2](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#select-2):

> For tables of type ordered_set, objects are ***visited in the same order as in a first/next traversal***. This means that the match
> specification is executed against objects with keys in the first/next
> order and ***the corresponding result list is in the order of that
> execution***.

[ets:first/1](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#first-1):

> Returns the first key Key in table Tab. For an ordered_set table, ***the
> first key in Erlang term order is returned***.

[Table Traversal](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#table-traversal):

> Traversals using `match` and `select` functions may not need to scan
> the entire table depending on how the key is specified. A match
> pattern with a fully bound key (without any match variables) will
> optimize the operation to a single key lookup without any table
> traversal at all. For ordered_set a partially bound key will limit the
> traversal to only scan a subset of the table based on term order.

It would make no sense to me for a table of type `ordered_set` to return search results in a random order.